# SQL query employee database

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to find the company that pays the ***least total salary*** along with total salary paid.

The details are as follows,

```
works( empid, companyname, salary )
```

And my query looks like,

```
SELECT COMPANYNAME 
FROM WORKS 
WHERE SALARY=
  (SELECT MIN(SUM(SALARY)) 
  FROM 
      (SELECT SUM(SALARY) 
      FROM WORKS 
      GROUP BY COMPANYNAME) 
GROUP BY COMPANYNAME);
```

but this doesn't return any rows.

I am new to SQL so I hope you can reply to me in an easy to understand way.

Comment: Hi Anand, - as you may guess from Gordon's answer, it always helps to know your Oracle version, because different versions have different capabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query doesn't return any rows because you are looking for rows in your original table, `works`. In that table you don't have the **total** salary paid for any company, only the individual employee salaries, so of course the query will not return any rows. There isn't any individual employee whose salary equals the minimum TOTAL salary among companies.

There are many ways to solve this problem, but since you are a beginner, you should only look for solutions that use the basic SQL statements (even though you wouldn't use such a solution in production). Your goal right now is to learn how SQL works, not to get the fastest or most advanced solution.

With that said: First you will need to create a query that groups the rows by company and then choose the company (or the companies, if there is a tie for first place) with the lowest total salary. For this you need to use `GROUP BY`, as you already did. Then, to select from the GROUPS (not from the original rows), you need to use the `HAVING` clause, not the `WHERE` clause. Something like this:

```
select   companyname, sum(salary) as total_salary
from     works
group by companyname 
having   sum(salary) = ( select   min(sum(salary))
                         from     works
                         group by companyname
                       )
;
```

Note also that SQL allows you to wrap an aggregate function within another - you can write `select min(sum(salary))` directly against the original table. This is illustrated in my subquery; compare to what you had in your original attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method in Oracle 12c+:

```
SELECT COMPANYNAME, SUM(SALARY) 
FROM WORKS 
GROUP BY COMPANYNAME
ORDER BY SUM(SALARY)
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

In older versions, use `ROW_NUMBER()`, `RANK()`, or `DENSE_RANK()`.  So, if there might be ties, then use:

```
SELECT w.*
FROM (SELECT COMPANYNAME, SUM(SALARY) as total_salary,
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(SALARY)) as seqnum
      FROM WORKS 
      GROUP BY COMPANYNAME
     ) w
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

This returns duplicates in the case of ties.  You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` if you want to guarantee that exactly one row is always returned.